# What is a safe edge in prims algorithm?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, prims-algorithm

For prims algorithm I understand how the algorithm works, but what exactly is a safe edge in this algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

A safe edge (u, v) is an edge that can be added to a subset of a Minimum Spanning Tree (MST) A such that this tree ( A U {(u, v)} ) won't lose this property.